# Extract ZIP code after State abbreviation

Tags: string, vba, excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel file with the full mailing address of several customers, and I need to fill a column with only the 5-digit zip codes, which always follow the same state abbreviation, "TX." Sometimes a 'phone number is added behind the zip code, and sometimes it isn't.

If there is a way to select 5 digits after the `TX` and move that information to a new cell, down to the last row, I haven't found it yet. I'm completely new to VBA, just need it for a one time job. Example:

D3 has `Namey Name Streety Street TX 75029 432-239-2490`
D4 has `Namity Names Streetick Street TX 73902`

I want to move `75029` to F3 and `73902` to F4 respectively.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7293461/62576 shows you how to extract part of a string. You should be able to easily modify it to work with finding the digits after `Tx `.

Answer (score 3):

"for a one time job" VBA seems overkill and even a formula not necessary. Just copy ColumnD into ColumnF, select ColumnF and with Replace... (HOME > Editing, Find & Replace), Find what:

`*TX`

(there is a space after the `X`),

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>, followed by Find what:

`*`

(there is a space before the `*`)

<kbd>Replace All</kbd>.

Comment: Very nice answer pnuts. I will file this one away for my own use :).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this excel formula?

```
=MID(D3,FIND(" TX ",D3)+4,5)
```

in F3 Then drag down

Answer (score 0):

Replace s with your input and put zip where you want it to go.

```
    Dim s As String
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim zip As String

    s = "Namey Name Streety Street TX 75029 432-239-2490"

    idx = InStr(1, UCase(s), " TX ")

    If idx > 0 Then
        zip = Mid(s, idx + 4, 5)
    Else
        zip = "Not found"
    End If
```