# VBA/excel extract multiple strings between symbols in cell

Tags: string, vba, excel, data-cleaning

I have a spreadsheet with multiple cells with a bunch of text in them. Within the text are a few words/sentences between @ symbols. There are multiple of these strings in each cell.

So for example:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, **@consectetur adipiscing elit@**. Curabitur sapien nibh, faucibus ut odio ut, vehicula elementum nunc. **@Fusce consequat risus vel dui tincidunt@** condimentum.

I need a solution to extract the @...@ strings, let's say into the adjacent column.

Edit to respond to comments: No solution could be attempt fully yet before making this post as I didn't know how to start - the main challenge seems to be around multiple @...@ strings in the text.

Other solutions I researched did not seem to work with multiple delimiters:

[excel vba- extract text between 2 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293461/excel-vba-extract-text-between-2-characters)

Any solutions are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You could go `Data` > `Text To Columns` and split it into separate columns using `@` as a **delimiter**.

Comment: Please read [*Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/1188513).

Comment: @simon: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [MCVE] , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: @simon: please show us [what you have tried](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, x, i As Long, ii As Long

a = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    x = Split(a(i, 1), " @")
    For ii = 1 To UBound(x)
        Cells(i, ii + 1).Value = Mid(x(ii), 1, InStr(x(ii), "@") - 1)
    Next ii
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this works partially. This splits every string with a space before the first @ delimiter. So "text text @string@." splits "string" correctly but for "text text@string@." nothing is split.

Comment: I depended on your first example .. Try tweaking that to suit your needs