# Changing numbers in each column into the substring of each column title

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Using Excel, I'm trying to accomplish the following:

Sample of before & after
[image: Sample of before & after]

I need to convert all the 1's into the corresponding country name of each column. With a small dataset like the sample above, it is easy to do it manually, but not so easy when I have 196 columns x 2 datasets. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: If you want it in place then formulas will not do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293461/excel-vba-extract-text-between-2-characters
Try using this along with a loop to look at your column headers to find country name and then you can find/replace 1's with the identified country name.

Comment: "If you want it in place then formulas will not do it" @Scott Craner   Right right. A formula can't do it in place.  But a custom number format can!

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious I would be interested in the custom format that would do what the options wants

Comment: @Scott Craner in separate cells enter   1   0   R   -1 
 create custom number format.  In the type field, key "Horse" ; "Richard" ; "Donkey" ; "Punch"  click through and go back to your sheet observe result.  Added bonus, they are still numbers so Horse + Richard = Donkey.  You can also use conditionals like [>=6]"Sallie" 
 Sadly Sallie said this method limits output to 4 options but you can use custom formatting to add more.  Just use a new custom number format instead of the traditional color changes.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious I thought you had one that you could apply to all the columns. Each column would need a separate format. I was hoping you had a way to do a lookup

Comment: @Scott Craner a second format is not needed for others columns if using the data set in the example.  The limitation is the number of available choices.  The example has 6 possible choices.  The number format itself can handle a maximum of 4 choices, conditional formatting on top of the custom number can handle all 6 and can be set for one cell and copied to any range where it is needed. This is a fringe use case with better options and it is why I only mention it in the comments. That said, custom numbers are very helpful, sometimes powerful, and worth learning.

Comment: It would if the OP wanted to keep the current setup.  @ProfoundlyOblivious  I know about how to use custom formatting and do so routinely, I just could not figure out how you would use it with the current format as a single code.

Comment: @Scott Craner Correct, this is not a "lookup".  Quotes used because it is a lookup, but not the type most commonly meant in Excel.  Another point to consider is that the OP used an integer as a flag so we can not presume math is not done unless explicitly stated.  Using only 4 choices, we would have one positive and one negative integer, zero, and a non-numerical text character and with 6 values you introduce two more unequal integers.  Any math now requires unnecessary complexity. I assure you, I would have used the answer section if i thought this was a good solution to the OP's question.

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious in the end I was hoping to learn something new.  Thanks for the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the sheet and clear all the values except the header in the second sheet. Put the following formula in every corresponding cell except the header row in the second sheet.

```
=IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,"Sheet1"),TRUE)=1,
    MID(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())),
        FIND("[",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())))+1,
        FIND("]",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())))-
            FIND("[",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMN())))-1),"")
```

You can then copy the corresponding cells of the second sheet. Past values into the first sheet. You're done.

{You'll want to remove carriage returns from the formula. Also, you might want to delete the second sheet to hide the magic. :-) }

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use vba instead of a formula, I think that this will work for you. It looks for non-empty cells within `"A:F"` and for those cells it grabs the name inside of `[...]`

```
Sub AdjustName()

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A2:F" & LastRowInRange_Find(Range("A:F")))
        If Len(cell.Value2) > 0 Then
            With Cells(1, cell.Column)
                cell.Value2 = Mid(.Value2, InStr(.Value2, "[") + 1, Len(.Value2) - 1 - InStr(.Value2, "["))
            End With
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub


Function LastRowInRange_Find(ByVal rng As Range) As Long

    'searches range from bottom up looking for "*" (anything)
    Dim rngFind As Range
    Set rngFind = rng.Find( _
                            What:="*", _
                            After:=Cells(rng.row, rng.Column), _
                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
        LastRowInRange_Find = rngFind.row
    Else
        LastRowInRange_Find = rng.row
    End If

End Function
```