# How to Dim and Set a variable workbook name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, variables

I have a workbook that gets created every week that has a variable name structure.  The name structure is as follows : `Week of Year` & `Invoice` & `date`.  So a sample file might be called `1_Invoice_01052018.xlsm`

I have to update the report every week.  I want to declare the variable workbook name as a variable in VBA. I have another workbook that contains the output of the report that is created via VBA.  In this other workbook I want to be able to call the `Invoice` spreadsheet but since it has a variable name, I am having issues finding it.  So I put together the VBA below.

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set wb = "*Invoice*" & ".xlsm"
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

wb.Activate
ws.Select

End Sub
```

However, this results in a "Type mismatch" error.

I also tried the following:

```
Sub Test2()

Windows("*Invoice*" & ".xlsm").Activate

End Sub
```

This also resulted in an error.

Any ideas on how to set a variable workbook name as a variable in VBA? I would only have one of these workbooks open at a time, so I wouldn't run into any issues

Comment: Loop through your open `Workbook` Objects until `Workbook.Name Like "Invoice*.xlsm"`, and then use that Object?

Answer (score 5):

You have to set the workbook correctly:

```vb
Sub Test()

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
 
  Dim FilePath As String
  FilePath = "C:\" & AnotherVariable & ".xlsx"

  Set wb = Workbooks(FilePath)
  Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

  wb.Activate
  ws.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't know the `File Path` because the file has a variable name.  I have two workbooks `A` and `B`.  `A` contains a macro that uses `B` to create an additional report.  I need to be able to reference workbook `B` as a variable in workbook `A` but since `B` has variable name, I'm not sure how to set it as a variable.  Both files would be open at the same time, so I would think I should be able to access that workbook.

Answer (score 2):

To create a new workbook you'd use [Workbooks.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.add). To open an existing one you'd use [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open) and then reference the worksheet within that workbook.
To change the name of the file you'd save it with a new name using the [SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) method.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim FileName As String

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add 'Creates a new workbook with default name.
    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open("<path to folder>\" & FileName & ".xlsm") 'Open an existing file.

    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    wb.SaveAs "<path to folder>\" & FileName & ".xlsm" 'Save and rename here.

    With ws
        .Range("A1") = "Adding some text to this cell"
    End With

End Sub
```

As a further example, the code below will create two workbooks before copying the sheet from the first workbook to the end of the second workbook.

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Create first workbook so it contains only 1 sheet (xlWBATWorksheet)
    ', reference Sheet1 and add some data to it.
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Range("A1") = "This cell populated in first workbook."

    'Create second workbook with default number of sheets
    'and copy Sheet1 from first book to the end of this one.
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add
    ws.Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(wb1.Sheets.Count)

End Sub
```

**Edit again:**

To figure out the workbook name based on `WeekNumber_Invoice_Date` you could use:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sPath As String
    Dim dDate As Date

    dDate = Date 'Todays date
    sPath = "C:\MyFolder\"
    sPath = sPath & _
        WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(dDate, 2) & "_Invoice_" & Format(dDate, "ddmmyyyy") & ".xlsm"

    'Open if already exists.
    'Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sPath)

    'Create and SaveAs new name.
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    wb.SaveAs sPath

End Sub
```

This would give a file path of `C:\MyFolder\43_Invoice_22102018.xlsm` based on todays date of *22nd October '18*.

Note:  The [WEEKNUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.weeknum) function considers the week containing January 1 to be the first week of the year.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I need from the following link:
[excel-vba-extract-text-between-2-characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293461/excel-vba-extract-text-between-2-characters)

I reviewed the link above and put together the VBA below.

```
Sub test2()

Dim str As String
Dim openPos As Integer
Dim closePos As Integer
Dim midBit As String

str = Range("b1").Value
openPos = InStr(str, "[")
closePos = InStr(str, "]")
midBit = Mid(str, openPos + 1, closePos - openPos - 1)

'MsgBox (midBit)
Windows(midBit).Activate

End Sub
```

I ended up creating a dynamic file path in cell `B1` that contained a concatenated file path string that contained look ups to pull in the `Week of Year` and `Date` based on the `Current Date`.  Since this path is dynamic it will always point to the right path given that I open the `Invoice` on the correct week.  I pulling the file name from the path and opening based on the file name which is dynamic.

Comment: Ah, right.... you extract the file name from the path in cell `B1`.  You missed that bit out of your question.  I wouldn't use `Windows(midBit).Activate`.  From there you'll be using `ActiveWorkbook` or something like - so if the activeworkbook gets changed before the code finishes you'll get the wrong results.  Go with `Set wb = Workbooks(midBit)` instead.  You can then use code like `WB.Save` or `WB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = "Some Value"` and the code won't care which workbook is active - it will always reference the correct one.